# Find index of header column of tsv file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

i have a tsv file with columns header. 
for eg: 
`Name group town age`
One of the column is 'age'. Now i want to output complete row, where age is greater than or equal to 50.

I did the following:

```
if (file.name === 'participant.tsv'){
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    var values = row.split('\t');
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      var headers = rows[0].split('\t');
      var ageIdColumn = headers.indexOf('age');
      var value = values[j]
      // age = Number(value)
        if (value == 89 || value > 89) {
            do so as so;
        };
```

But no luck.. can someone point out where i am making mistake?

The above script works when age is 89 but when age is above 89 it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

you can get `ageIndex` first (since its static) then loop through `rows`

when condition `age >= 50` is true, push that row in to `filteredRows`

```js
var filteredRows = [];
var headers = rows[0].split('\t');
var ageIndex = headers.indexOf('age');

if (file.name === 'participant.tsv') {
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    var age = row.split('\t')[ageIndex];
    if (Number(age) >= 50) filteredRows.push(row);
  });
}
```

Comment: apparently the above script is not working. when i print, age it gives me undefined